# How to obtain eigenvalue in free Fermi gas problem?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics

I’m trying to compare the energies of the $N$ particle free Fermi gas with the following two wave functions. They are supposed to have the same energy

Let $\psi_l(\vec{r})$ be the single-electron wavefunction that obeys

$$\left(\frac{-h^2 \nabla^2}{2m} + U(\vec{r}) \right) \psi_l(\vec{r}) = E_l \psi_l(\vec{r})$$

where $E_l$ is the energy.

Then, we have two wavefunctions of $N$ electrons, made up with the functions for single electrons, which are supposed to have the same energy. They are

$$\Psi_A = \prod_{l=1}^N \psi_l (\vec{r}_l)$$

$$\Psi_B = \frac{1}{N!} \sum_s (-1)^s \prod_{l=1}^N \psi_{sl}(\vec{r}_l)$$

Where the sum goes over the permutations of $N$ elements, $(-1)^s$ is the parity of the permutation and the sub index $sl$ goes over the elements in each permutation.

I was able to find that the eigenvalue for the $A$ wavefunction is 
$$\sum_{l=1}^N E_l$$

But I am unable to do it for $\Psi_B$

How is this done?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're missing an important part of the question that you can't expect mathematicians to know – that the Hamiltonian for the $N$-particle system is the sum of the $1$-particle Hamiltonians and "free Fermi gas" means no interaction terms.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each term in the sum contains the same one-particle wavefunctions as $\psi_A$, just with different permutations of the coordinates. Each of these terms is an eigenfunction of the $N$-particle Hamiltonian just like $\psi_A$, with the same eigenvalue. Forming a linear combination of these eigenfunctions again yields an eigenfunction with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: My problem is why do the permutations of the coordinates not affect the eigenvalue?

Comment: @TheBosco: How could they? What's special about the permutation you chose for $A$? You arbitrarily labeled the $1$-particle wavefunctions (well, perhaps you labeled them in order of increasing energy, but you didn't need to and you didn't use that), and then you arbitrarily assigned one of the $1$-particle wavefunctions to each coordinate -- what could change if you now permute this arbitrary assignment into another arbitrary assignment? The more formal answer is: Because the Hamiltonian commutes with the permutation operators.